# Angular 2 seed project failing to webpack when running NPM START

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack-dev-server

So I downloaded the angular2-seed project from GITHUB and am trying to get it running. I'm using the latest versions of NPM and NODE.

This is the error I'm seeing when running. I've changed the port on webpack and also have changed the port on the server as well as running sudo/non-sudo with the same results.

```

```
xxx:angular2-seed xxx$ sudo npm start

angular2-seed@1.0.0 start /Users/XX/Desktop/ANGULAR_TESTING/angular2-seed
npm run server
angular2-seed@1.0.0 server /Users/XX/Desktop/ANGULAR_TESTING/angular2-seed
webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 8080 --content-base src
57% 8/10 build modulesError: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 122.122.122.122:8080
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1244:19)
at listen (net.js:1293:10)
at net.js:1403:9
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "server"
npm ERR! node v6.8.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-seed@1.0.0 server: webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 8080 --content-base src
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-seed@1.0.0 server script 'webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 8080 --content-base src'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 8080 --content-base src
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs angular2-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls angular2-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Users/XX/Desktop/ANGULAR_TESTING/angular2-seed/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.8.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-seed@1.0.0 start: npm run server
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-seed@1.0.0 start script 'npm run server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! npm run server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs angular2-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls angular2-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Users/XX/Desktop/ANGULAR_TESTING/angular2-seed/npm-debug.log
```

```

Comment: I would guess your localhost address is not `122.122.122.122`. I would suggest changing that to `127.0.0.1` somehow

Comment: It was using the IP of the machine..I obfuscated it for the post...It was reporting the IP adress of the laptop

Answer (score 0):

The port 8080 is already in use.

Change the port at:

https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/blob/master/package.json
on scripts.server

Comment: nope...started at 3000 and went to 8080 and it failed on both.